# Can we calculate the nearest location between 2 locations?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

We have a SharePoint list which stores the Assets' locations (Latitude & Longitude).

When a support ticket is created for an asset >> Technicians will get an email that a support ticket was created for an asset >> so they need to login to Power Apps and send their location.

So at the end we will have 2 SharePoint lists; first one which stores the current technicians' Latitude and Longitude + second one which stores the related Asset Latitude and Longitude.

Then i want to trigger a workflow which calculate the nearest technician from the asset (nearest route using vehicle) and send him/her an email. so is this possible inside power automate to calculate the nearest route between 2 coordinations (The Asset coordination & The Technicians coordination) ?

So can we benefit from Bing Maps connector to solve this issue?